# how to completely remove snippet from blogspot post

Tags: blogger, code-snippets

I am using my own custom contempo theme
How to completely remove the snippet in a blogspot post without affecting the snippet in the feature post, like in feature post in blogspot[image: this image]

Feature post have toggle to turn off snippet,but other post and popular post not feature post don't have this toggle.I used css to hidden snippet,but i don't like this way.I want to completely remove the snippet by using code in xml or anything else

```
</b:includable>
        <b:includable id='userProfileText'>
      <dd class='profile-textblock profile-snippet snippet-container r-snippet-container'>
        <div class='snippet-item r-snippetized'>
          <data:aboutme/>
        </div>
        <div class='snippet-fade r-snippet-fade hidden'/>
      </dd>
```

Comment: I think you can set that off in the settings of the Featured post in the Layout tab. Anyway, that piece of code you presented looks to me that it's for your profile not the text snippet you looking for...

Comment: @Osvaldo Correia  i don't find option to turn off snippet in main post,only find it in featured post

Comment: My bad, I thought you meant Featured Post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Contempo template, look for `<b:include cond='data:post' data='post' name='postSnippet'/>` and change it to:

```
<!--<b:include cond='data:post' data='post' name='postSnippet'/>-->
```

Be careful, there are four (4) lines with the same code.
Test to see wich one hide the piece of text you want.

I hope this is what you looking for.